# How to Edit uploded photo symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, doctrine-orm

I have Symfony 2.4 web application and I need to update photo but when I call edit_form it always gives null to photo field instead it had a photo uploaded when first create ,

So the problem is how to pass the photo as file to the form ? 
Or what is the best practise I should go for ?

Any help will be appreciated.

in EtudiantController

```
 private function createEditForm(Etudiant $entity)
{
  $form = $this->createForm(new EtudiantType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('etudiant_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

    return $form;
}
```

and in my EtudiantType

```
->add('photo', 'file', array(
            'data_class' => null
        ))
```

and Etudiant.php

```
/**
 * @var string $photo
 * @Assert\File( maxSize = "1024k", mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid Image")
 * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="string", length=255)
 */
public $photo;


/**
 * Set photo
 *
 * @param string $photo
 * @return Animateur
 */
public function setPhoto($photo)
{
    $this->photo = $photo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get photo
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPhoto()
{
    return $this->photo;
}


public function getFullImagePath() {
    return null === $this->photo ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir(). $this->photo;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir() {
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
    return $this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->getId()."/";
}

protected function getTmpUploadRootDir() {
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
    return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/upload/';
}


public function uploadImage() {
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if (null === $this->photo) {
        return;
    }
    if(!$this->id){
        $this->photo->move($this->getTmpUploadRootDir(), $this->photo->getClientOriginalName());
    }else{
        $this->photo->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->photo->getClientOriginalName());
    }
    $this->setPhoto($this->photo->getClientOriginalName());
}


public function moveImage()
{
    if (null === $this->photo) {
        return;
    }
    if(!is_dir($this->getUploadRootDir())){
        mkdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
    }
    copy($this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->photo, $this->getFullImagePath());
    unlink($this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->photo);
}


public function removeImage()
{
    unlink($this->getFullImagePath());
    rmdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
}


/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    // Add your code here
}
```

Comment: could you add the `updateAction` method that is handling the update form ?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the official documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html), you should have two fields, one for the already uploaded and stored image and the other one for the form to handle:

```
/**
 * @var string $photo
 * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="string", length=255)
 */
public $photo;

/**
 * @Assert\File( maxSize = "1024k", mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid Image")
 */
public $uploadedPhoto;
```

Then you only add the 'uploadedPhoto' field to your form:

```
->add('uploadedPhoto', 'file'))
```

If you need to show the current image, you can access your `Etudiant` entity from your Twig template, as long as you pass it from the controller. Once the form is submitted and validated it's just a matter of coyping the uploaded photo to the final folder and updating the `photo` property with the new value.